# mysql trigger does not work if value is null

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to track all changes of a specific column and store them to another table. This works if processed_at is updated to a value except when it is null. However I would expect that this condition

> if NEW.processed_at != OLD.processed_at then

is also true if the old value is not null and the new is null, but it does not insert a new row to the processed_changes table in that case.

```
create definer = xxx@`%` trigger processed_change_on_update
    after update
    on results
    for each row
begin
    if NEW.processed_at != OLD.processed_at then
        insert into processed_changes (result_id, operation, old_processed_at, new_processed_at)
        values (NEW.id, 'update', OLD.processed_at, NEW.processed_at);
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: When operand is NULL then the result is NULL too. NULL is treated as FALSE. You must use [NULL-safe compare](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to). `... if NOT NEW.processed_at <=> OLD.processed_at then ...`

Comment: you can make it an answer

Comment: I'm lazy... you may create self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a null safe comparison saved the problem.

From Akinas comment:

> When operand is NULL then the result is NULL too. NULL is treated as
> FALSE.  You must use NULL-safe compare.  if NOT NEW.processed_at <=>
> OLD.processed_at then